# How to achieve LINQ SUM with multiple columns with no group by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, sum

I am getting the data correctly. But I want to get the TotalRuns ie if is in SQL Query, I can write it as
`(SUM(pts.Run1)+SUM(pts.Run2)+SUM(pts.Run3)+SUM(pts.Run4)+Sum(pts.Run6)) As totalRuns`
How can I achieve this in LINQ ?

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285710/linq-to-sql-join-and-sum) one but it gives a syntax error.

This is my LINQ Query.

```
          var playerScore = from pts in Oritia_entities.PlayerTeamSeasons
          join p in Oritia_entities.Players on new { ID = pts.PlayerId } 
    equals new { ID = p.ID }
           join c in Oritia_entities.Crews on new { ID = p.CrewId } 
    equals new { ID = c.ID }
           join f in Oritia_entities.Fixtures on new { ID = pts.FixtureId } 
equals new { ID = f.Id }
          where c.ID == playerID && pts.SeasonId == seasonID
            select new PlayerScore
                                              {
                                                  BallsFaced = (int)pts.BallsFaced,
                                                  Run1 = (int)pts.Run1,
                                                  Run2 = (int)pts.Run2,
                                                  Run3 = (int)pts.Run3,
                                                  Run4 = (int)pts.Run4,
                                                  Run6 = (int)pts.Run6,

                                                  BallsBowled = (int)pts.BallsBowled,
                                                  RunsGiven = (int)pts.RunsGiven,
                                                  Wickets = (int)pts.Wickets,
                                                  Catches = (int)pts.Catches,
                                                  Dot = (int)pts.Dot,
                                                  NoBall = (int)pts.NoBall,
                                                  RunOutBy = (int)pts.RunOutBy,
                                               //   Match = (t1.T + " v/s " + f.Team2)

                                              };
```

I am using .Net 4.0

Comment: What _exactly_ do you want to achieve? The sum of all runs in all fixtures of a player in a season? And let that sum be part of the `PlayerScore` record?

Comment: I love how I didn't realise this was cricket related until I came back to the question after 24 hours...

Comment: Yes. I just want to calculatete the player's score ")

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10239987/get-sum-of-two-columns-in-one-linq-query-without-grouping/10247189#10247189

Comment: @GertArnold  i searched a lot before asking asking , any way thanks for the link. Will try that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to totalRuns for each row, then you can do

```
{
    BallsFaced = (int)pts.BallsFaced,
    Run1 = (int)pts.Run1,
    Run2 = (int)pts.Run2,
    Run3 = (int)pts.Run3,
    Run4 = (int)pts.Run4,
    Run6 = (int)pts.Run6,
    TotalRuns = (int)pts.Run1 + (int)pts.Run2 + (int)pts.Run3 ...,
    BallsBowled = (int)pts.BallsBowled,
    RunsGiven = (int)pts.RunsGiven,
    Wickets = (int)pts.Wickets,
    Catches = (int)pts.Catches,
    Dot = (int)pts.Dot,
    NoBall = (int)pts.NoBall,
    RunOutBy = (int)pts.RunOutBy,
    //   Match = (t1.T + " v/s " + f.Team2)
};
```

If you want the total runs for ALL rows, after the query you could do:

```
var sum = playerScore.Select(x=>x.TotalRuns).Sum();
```

or if you didn't have TotalRuns as a field, just move the addition of each row to the lamba:

```
var sum = playerScore.Select(x=>x.Run1 + Run2 + Run3 ...).Sum();
```

Comment: Is there is anything equivalent of SQL SUM ?